# To say “In return, you buy me dinner”: “im Gegenzug”, "als Gegenleistung", or “zum Ausgleich”?

Tags: word-choice

In conversation with my friend, I said:

> Ich begleite dich also, aber **im Gegenzug** lädst du mich später zum Abendessen ein.

I wonder how the following two would have compared and which would have been the best option in this context?

> Ich begleite dich also, aber **als Gegenleistung** lädst du mich später zum Abendessen ein.
>
> Ich begleite dich also, aber **zum Ausgleich** lädst du mich später zum Abendessen ein.

Comment: All three are fine. The last one implies it's a burden which really needs a compensation. The other two are friendly banter.

Comment: @Janka Interesting nuance! Incidentally, which is more commonly used: "zum Ausgleich" or "als Ausgleich"?

Comment: In a conversation with a friend, I would just say "..., dafür lädst du mich später...". Probably colloquial, but I guess my friend would be really surprised if I as a native german speaker would use one of the three options above, at least in spoken german.

Comment: @aloNe-zee I think "zum Ausgleich" and "als Ausgleich" are equally common, at least here in Vienna...

Comment: @mischa.mole Hi. Speaking of "dafür", I was close to saying: "aber im Gegenzug dafür lädst du ...". I suppose this is too much? So... you think all these three are a bit too formal in register to be used colloquially, huh? :)

Comment: "im Gegenzug dafür" sounds a bit odd to me, although it is grammatically correct (I think?) ..."als Ausgleich dafür" works better.

Comment: @mischa.mole why don’t you make this an answer? Answering in comments is discouraged - and I can’t upvote ;-)

Comment: *Zum Ausgleich* and *als Ausgleich* are equally uncommon, I think.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to say that is "dafür" like in

> Ich begleite dich, aber **dafür** lädst du mich dann zum Abendessen ein

Your proposals are also possible but would be considered a bit on the formal side.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is rather opinion based and all three variances have very small differences. I disagree to the comment that these are not used in common speech, they are. I would say I hear them almost the same amount. I would like to characterize each as following, but again, all are nearly equal and can be used in a conversation with a friend, personally I have following connotations:

**Gegenzug** comes probably from chess, so it is the most intelligent and well thought reaction to something, so it does not fit well for leisure things.

**Gegenleistung** is most formal, rather said in a business or working context.

**Ausgleich** is neutral, for me it sounds less offensive.

Answer (score 0):

Tofros **dafür** (siehe andere Antwort) ist die beste, weil einfachste und natürlichste Ausdrucksform. Gut und auch weit verbreitet ist daneben noch:

> Okay, ich begleite dich; und du **revanchierst dich** mit einem Abendessen.

*Revanche* ist in der Grundbedeutung zwar die Rache und Vergeltung, jedoch ist es durchaus üblich, es auch für Taten mit positivem Affektgehalt zu benützen.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it is similar to "À charge de ***revanche*** !" in French. :)

Answer (score 0):

Of the three options you presented, I like `im Gegenzug` best, as it explains that paying for dinner references some past event, but does not imply some (formal, legal or financial) obligation like `als Gegenleistung` does. `Zum Ausgleich` implies that there is something in quantitive unbalance, though.

The option `dafür` is probably the best alternative, at least in informal, spoken conversations.

Answer (score -1):

**Classification:** friendship-as-business question

**Answer:** The

> »Kannst du mir helfen?«
>   »Was zahlst du?«

behaviour isn't common even among Germans. Friends usually don't ask for a reward when doing a favour.

Therefore, if you cannot abstain from a service in return, I recommend to drop a hint instead of talking directly:

> Da wird mir heute Abend aber ganz schön der Magen knurren!